# Generating PDF from AsciiDoc using Maven and place it in a different module

Tags: maven, asciidoc

I am using Maven and have multiple modules in my project. One module of my project is "documentation". There I made some AsciiDoc and in the pom file of the "documentation" module I put something to build the PDF and HTML of my AsciiDoc (I am using AsciiDoctor). For example for the PDF's output file I use this:

`<outputFile>${project.build.directory}\generated-docs\MyDocument.pdf</outputFile>`

This is working fine. Now I want to place this PDF into a different module "distribution", which is also a module of my project, and is at the same level as "documentation". I was thinking of adding some dependency in my "distribution" to my "documentation" module to be able then to put the PDF in a subfolder "documents" of "distribution". However, I don't know how I can do this, because I don't know how to access something from a different module in the pom of "distribution". Or is there another/better way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either you _know_ where to put the file in your file system or you need to add it as an artifact to Maven.  You can attach it to your current module with a classifier and then refer to that as a dependency in another module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving my goal by using a file "translate.xml" that specifies the generated pdf and specifies as an output the distribution folder in a FileSet. Then in my pom I use maven-assembly-plugin to take this translate.xml file and place my pdf in a zip in the distribution folder.